# Assign values to navigation property when adding new entity with BreezeJS

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I have two models:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set;}
    public int GroupID { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group {get; set;}
}

public partial class Group
{
    public int GroupID { get; set;}
    public string GroupName { get; set;}
}
```

Whenever I create a new user in the UI, I will also assign the group to the user through the dropdown list. I will retrieve the group entity from the selected value in the dropdown and assign it to the navigation property when creating the user entity.

```
groupEntity = { GroupID: 1, GroupName: ABCD }; // group entity retrieved from dropdown
manager.createEntity('User' {
  FullName: 'Boon',
  Group: groupEntity
});
```

The following returns me an error.

```
An Entity cannot be attached to an entity in another EntityManager. One of the two entities must be detached first.
```

So I detached the entity from the breeze manager that retrieves it and it returns me another error when creating.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot attach this entity because the EntityType (Group:#Data) and MetadataStore associated with this entity does not match this EntityManager's MetadataStore.
```

Entity Framework Code

```
readonly EFContextProvider<EFEntities> _context = new EFContextProvider<EFEntities>();
[HttpGet]
public string Metadata()
{
    return _context.Metadata();
} 

[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Data.User> GetUsers()
{
    return _context.Context.Users
        .Include("Group");     
}

[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject user)
{
    return _context.SaveChanges(user);
}
```

Any advice on how do I assign the navigation property to a preset values when adding a new entity?

Comment: can you show the EF related queries?

Comment: just appended them into post above.

Comment: You shouldn't be setting virtual properties directly, except when pushing to an ICollection. You should be setting the GroupID on User instead

Comment: Also, how many managers do you have? If you have multiple then the error is pretty clear

Comment: I tried setting the GroupID on the user in the User's Constructor but to no avail. It still says INSERT Statement failed due to foreign key constraint. As for the managers, I tried doing everything under a single manager instead of multiple and yet it failed.